# Slide menu display same for all pages Android

Tags: android, menu, slide

I am trying to make an App on android. I have made the slide in menu bar like the one shown in the the picture below. The blue bar. Now what I want is that my every screen should show the same menu options. Not those with the back button. How do I do that? Should I make one header and call that in every class? Right now I have an Activity and everything else is a fragment.

I can post my code here as well. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make a Parent Activity and make this acion bar in it.inherit your all activities from this parent activity and just remove  `setContentView(R.layout.layoutname)` from your  child activity.
this works in your scenario when you are using fragments so you don't need the layout for activity. so your fragment container would be your parent activity..

Comment: What if I have made all the screens as activity classes and integrating the slide menu with it now? then what should I do?